# Stop nodes/vertices overlapping in igraph.plot

Tags: r, plot, nodes, igraph, vertices

I have a table of nodes to be plotted in R and am using `igraph.plot` as it seems to be the best suited to my needs.

Not all the nodes in my graph are connected, i.e. some part of the overall graph may just contain a pair of connected nodes.  I need to produce a series of node-edge graphs all represented in the same figure where none of the vertices overlap.

I have tried multiple layouts but I think it is because not all the nodes are connected to one another that they plot this way...

Does anyone know of a way to plot these without the nodes overlapping?

(I've tried to included two images below but it seems I need "reputation points" :/ )

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you productive your adjacency matrix?

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the `layout` [functions](http://igraph.org/r/doc/layout_.html) and editing sizes of the edges and vertex of your network. Try with this:

```
plot(G, vertex.size=8, vertex.color = rainbow(10, .8, .8, alpha= .8),
vertex.label.color = "black", vertex.label.cex = 0.4, vertex.label.degree = -pi/2,
edge.arrow.size = 0.3, edge.arrow.width = 0.4, edge.color = "black")
```